# Bdb StoredList in java

Tags: java, list, berkeley-db-je

I have a list object which is making my program to crash by out of memory error. I want to convert the list to BDB StoredList. But I am getting exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

RecordNumberBinding requires `DB_BTREE/DB_RECNUM, DB_RECNO, or DB_QUEUE`. Is there any way I can cache my list to disk so that It doesn't crash my program.
Any pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net I used disk based data structures. Try investigating this topic for java.